# C# textbox to database - error: C# doesn't know my column name: username & password

Tags: c#, database

My Visual Studio program doesn't know my column names.

Here is a picture of my table "tblAccount": [image: tables]

Here is a picture of my error message: [image: error]

Here is my code:

```
public partial class frmInloggen : Form
{
    SqlConnection loonberekening;
    frmStartmenu startmenu;

    string usernaam, wachtwoord, bevoegdheid;
    int userID, wachtwoordID;

    public frmInloggen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initialiseerDB();
        startmenu = new frmStartmenu();
    }

    private void initialiseerDB()
    {
        loonberekening = new SqlConnection();
        loonberekening.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       usernaam = txtGebruikersnaam.Text;
        wachtwoord = txtPaswoord.Text;

        SqlCommand scmdUsername, scmdWachtwoord, scmdBevoegdheid;
        scmdUsername = new SqlCommand();
        scmdWachtwoord = new SqlCommand();
        scmdBevoegdheid = new SqlCommand();

        scmdUsername.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdWachtwoord.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdBevoegdheid.Connection = loonberekening;

        scmdUsername.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        scmdWachtwoord.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        scmdBevoegdheid.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        scmdUsername.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE usernaam = \'" + usernaam + "\'";
        scmdWachtwoord.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE wachtwoord = \'" + wachtwoord + "\'";
        bevoegdheid = Convert.ToString(scmdBevoegdheid);
        scmdBevoegdheid.CommandText = "SELECT rechten FROM tblAccount WHERE bevoegdheid = \'" + userID + "\'";

        loonberekening.Open();
        userID = Convert.ToInt32(scmdUsername.ExecuteScalar());
        wachtwoordID = Convert.ToInt32(scmdWachtwoord.ExecuteScalar());

        loonberekening.Close();

       if (userID == wachtwoordID && userID > 0 && wachtwoordID > 0)
       {
               startmenu.Show();
       }
       else
       {
               MessageBox.Show("Password & username is wrong");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the problem?  Also, your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  It is a good idea to use parameterized queries, even when it is just for school, or early on in a project.

Comment: Visual studio doesnt know my column name: usernaam & wachtwoord in this sentence: "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE usernaam = \'" + usernaam + "\'"; and "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE wachtwoord = \'" + wachtwoord + "\'";  but if you click on the pictures above the code then you can see that usernaam & wachtwoord are my column names

Comment: Are you connecting to to correct database?  Were the appropriate access rights set up for the DB user?  Can you write this exact same query in a query editor and get results?  This is hard to to figure out without a lot more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Initial Catalog to your connection string:

```
loonberekening.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=<YOUR DATABASE NAME>;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be escaping your single quotes...

Try

```
scmdUsername.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE usernaam = '" + usernaam + "'";

scmdWachtwoord.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE wachtwoord = '" + wachtwoord + "'";
bevoegdheid = Convert.ToString(scmdBevoegdheid);
scmdBevoegdheid.CommandText = "SELECT rechten FROM tblAccount WHERE bevoegdheid = '" + userID + "'";
```

instead of

```
scmdUsername.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE usernaam = \'" + usernaam + "\'";
scmdWachtwoord.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM tblAccount WHERE wachtwoord = \'" + wachtwoord + "\'";
bevoegdheid = Convert.ToString(scmdBevoegdheid);
scmdBevoegdheid.CommandText = "SELECT rechten FROM tblAccount WHERE bevoegdheid = \'" + userID + "\'";
```